# Trouble on creating HQL with Join Table (@ManyToMany)

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hql, join

I'm trying to make a HQL with a join table to work, but i just doesn't.

Here are my annotated classes (deleted not useful parts before posting here):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_usuarios")
public class Usuario {

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=Cliente.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "tab_usuarios_clientes", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_usuario") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_cliente") })
    private List<Cliente> clientes;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_pontos")
public class Ponto {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "GENERIC_SEQ_GEN")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "datahora")  
    private Date dataHora;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "tab_clientes")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "GENERIC_SEQ_GEN")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
}
```

Then I made the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tab_pontos p
INNER JOIN tab_usuarios_clientes uc ON p.fk_id_usuario = uc.fk_id_usuario
INNER JOIN tab_clientes c ON uc.fk_id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN tab_usuarios u ON uc.fk_id_usuario = u.id
WHERE c.id = ? AND uc.fk_id_usuario = ?
```

And I tried to 'translate' it to this HQL:

```
SELECT p FROM Ponto p
INNER JOIN Usuario.clientes uc INNER JOIN Cliente c
INNER JOIN Usuario u
WHERE c = u.clientes.id
AND u.nome = ?
ORDER BY p.dataHora DESC
```

So it gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'null.clientes' [SELECT p FROM br.mgx.ponto.dominio.Ponto p INNER JOIN Usuario.clientes uc INNER JOIN Cliente c INNER JOIN Usuario u WHERE c = Usuario.clientes.id AND u.nome = ? ORDER BY p.dataHora DESC]
```

What am I missing? I just can't find out what is wrong with my HQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joins in HQL consist in navigating from one entity to another using an association: `select u from User u inner join u.clientes` for example. Your query uses an unknown entity Ponto. And it tries using an entity name (like User) instead of an alias name (like u) to create a join: `INNER JOIN Usuario.clientes`, `INNER JOIN Cliente c`. In short, it isn't HQL at all. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html. If you want more help, post the relevant entities.

Comment: I added the entity Ponto for better understanding. Anyway I'll check the doc you just suggested.